# web-mode-indentation wrong

Tags: indentation, evil, web-mode

Using web-mode and evil I get a really strange behaviour when pressing return after curly braces:

```
let StubMapsService = Ember.Service.extend({
    getMapElement(location) { (RET)
        }
});

let f = function(assert) { (RET)
    }
```

RET is set to "evil-ret".

When writing java-files the Indentation is correct after inserting }.

Also when I press C-c TAB in web-mode, so web-mode auto-indents the buffer, then everything looks correct:

```
let StubMapsService = Ember.Service.extend({
    getMapElement(location) {
    }
});

let f = function(assert) {
}
```

I searched for an hour for a solution. I tried changing c-indent-offset, setting web-mode-code-indent-offset, but nothing helped. Turning off electric-indent-mode I get no indentation after pressing RET. Any Idea what is going wrong?

Comment: `web-mode` is probably assuming that you want to write something on that line. Does typing TAB on that line solve the problem?

Comment: Yes: I need to get out of insert-mode, jump in front of the closing bracket and then go back in insert-mode and press tab. Obviously this is not what I want. Like in java-files I want the right Indentation as soon as I type the closing bracket.